# Вызов функции с параметрами через событие

Tags: javascript

Я хочу вызывать функцию `validate()` с разными параметрами,т.е использовать повторно для валидации полей, во время события `input` на разных элементах `<input>` *(в примере, в конце ,принцип работы с одним `<input>`)*.

Но, если вызывать функцию с параметрами - `names.addEventListener('input',validateName(names, validname, iconrequiredname))` значение  как бы не обновляется и остается равным `' '` ничему, как сделать так чтобы переменная обновлялась во время события `input`?

Я пытался перебирать массив элементов *(если их несколько)* для каждой переменной с помощью `[].forEach.call()`:

```
var names = document.querySelectorAll('.name');

[].forEach.call(names, function () {
names.addEventListener('input', function() {
if (names.validity.valid) {

  } 
    }, false);
});
```

Но разумеется я могу передать только одну переменную с массивом, и доступ к ней есть только внутри тела функции.

Вопрос,как мне не переписывать одну и ту же функцию несколько раз и сделать одну функцию с параметрами и передавать их туда, что для этого использовать? Вложенный массив? Как это может выглядеть?

**Пример работы с одним `<input>`:**

```js
var names = document.getElementById('name');
var validname = document.getElementById('vn');

names.addEventListener('input', validate);

function validate() {
  if (names.validity.valid) {
    validname.className = "valid";

  } else {
    validname.className = "invalid";
  }
}
```

```css
 .invalid {
  width:12px;
 height:12px;
 position:absolute;
 right:15px;
 top: 12px;
    background:tomato;
 border-radius:6px;
 animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate inv;
 }
  .valid {
  width:12px;
 height:12px;
 position:absolute;
 right:15px;
 top: 12px;
 background:#9dc46b;
 border-radius:6px;
 animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite  alternate inv;
 }
 
 input:not([type="submit"])  {
  border-radius:100px;
 padding-left:15px;
  height:36px;
 border:none;
 background: #f3f3f3;
 font-size: 18px;

 }
 

 
 input:focus{
  outline:none;
    border:2px solid #f3f3f3;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 background:white;
 padding-left:13px;
 
 }

 .required {
  display:inline-flex;
 width:100%;
 flex-direction: column;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 position:relative;
 }
 
 .hide {
 display:none;
 }
```

```html
  <label class="required"><span id="vn" class="invalid hide"></span>
   <input id="name" class="mail" type="name" name="name" autocomplete= none value="" placeholder="имя...."  pattern="[А-Яа-яЁё]+(\s+[А-Яа-яЁё]+)?" maxlength="15" minlength="2" required><div id="namereq" class="iconrequired hide">ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО</div></label>
```

Решил примерно так:

```js
var names = document.querySelectorAll('.name');


[].forEach.call(names, function (names) {
 names.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  if (names.validity.valid) {
   e.target.previousElementSibling.className = "valid";
 
  }   else if (!names.validity.valid) {
   e.target.previousElementSibling.className = "invalid";
 
  } 
 
 }, false);
});
```

```css
  @font-face {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr-Thin";
  src: url("/fonts/HelveticaNeueCyr-Thin.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-display: swap;
   }

@keyframes req { 0% { transform:translatex(0px)    ; } 100% { transform:translatex(5px)   ; } }
 
 @keyframes inv { 0% { opacity:.5   ; } 100% { opacity:1    ; } }
 
   @keyframes hide { 0% { opacity:1   ; } 100% { opacity:0    ; } }
  @keyframes show { 0% { opacity:0  ; } 100% { opacity:1    ; } }
  
    @keyframes head { 0% { transform: translate(0%, 0%); top: 60px; left: 0; margin-right: 0; } 100% { top: 25%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); } }

* {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}


:root {
 font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr";
 font-weight:100;
}
 form {
   margin-top:100px;
   font-size: 24px;
   position: relative;
   width:100%;
   display: inline-flex;
   flex-direction: column;
 }

 

 header {
position:relative;
font-size:24px;
top: 60px;
position:absolute;

 }
 
 textarea {
   height: 30vh;
   border-radius: 18px;
   padding-left: 15px;
   padding-top:10px;
   border: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
   overflow: hidden;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   outline: none;
   resize: none
 }

 input,
 textarea {
   font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr";
   font-weight: 100;
   font-size: 18px;
 }

 
input:not([type="submit"])  {
  border-radius:100px;
 padding-left:15px;
  height:36px;
 border:none;
 background: #f3f3f3;
 font-size: 18px;

 }
 

 
 input:focus{
  outline:none;
    border:2px solid #f3f3f3;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 background:white;
 padding-left:13px;
 
 }

 .required {
  display:inline-flex;
 width:100%;
 flex-direction: column;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 position:relative;
 }
 .iconrequired{
  margin:auto;
  display:flex;
 align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  width:90px;
 height:14px;
 color: white;
 border-radius:100px;
  font-size:10px;
 font-weight:100;
 font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr";
 background:#343434;
 position:absolute;
 right:15px;
 top: 10px;
 opacity:1;
 transition: opacity ease-out 1s;
 animation: .05s ease-in-out 0s 4 alternate req;
  
  }

 

 input:-webkit-autofill,
 input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
 input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
 input:-webkit-autofill:active {
   transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
  border:2px solid #f3f3f3;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding-left:13px;
 }
 div.button-set {
   display: inline-flex;
 }
 div.button-set>label {
   position: relative;
   flex: 0 0 auto;
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   margin-left: 15px;
   border-radius: 100px;
   outline: none;
   border: none;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
 .checked {
   background: #eaeaea;
   border-radius: 100px;
 }

 input[type="submit"] {
   font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr";
   height: 36px;
   width: 160px;
   font-weight: 100;
   font-size: 24px;
   margin-top: 20px;
   margin-left: 10px;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 100px;
   background: #f3f3f3;
   padding:0;
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 9999;
   width: 5px;
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
   display: none;
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   z-index: 9999;
   background-color: transparent;
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
   z-index: 9999;
   z-index: 9999;
   background-color: transparent;
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   z-index: 9999;
   background-color: #d7d7d7;
   border-radius: 3px;
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
   z-index: 9999;
   background-color: #d7d7d7;
 }
 .invalid {
  width:12px;
 height:12px;
 position:absolute;
 right:15px;
 top: 12px;
    background:tomato;
 border-radius:6px;
 animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate inv;
 }
  .valid {
  width:12px;
 height:12px;
 position:absolute;
 right:15px;
 top: 12px;
 background:#9dc46b;
 border-radius:6px;
 animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite  alternate inv;
 }
.error {
 text-align:right;
 font-size:12px;
 padding-right:20px;
 padding-top:10px;
 color:gray;
 letter-spacing:.05em;
}


.g-recaptcha {
    right:0;
 margin-top:36px;

 }
 
   .message {
  position:absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s  alternate head;
 }
 
 
 .g { 
 
  display:inline-flex;
 margin-bottom:15px;

}

 .g>input:nth-child(2) { 
 

 margin-right:8px;
}

 .g>input:nth-child(3) { 
  margin-right:8px;
  

}
 .g>input:nth-child(4) { 


}
.files{
 display:inline-flex;
 font-size:18px;
 align-items: center;
  padding-left:16px;
 background: #f3f3f3;
 height:36px;
 width:40%;
 border-radius:100px;
}

 .hide {
  display:none;
 }
svg{
 margin-right:16px;
}

label[for="file"] {
 display:inline-flex;

  align-items: center;
}
.fff {
 
 background:red;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: gray;
   font-size: 18px;
 }

 ::-moz-placeholder {
   color: gray;
   font-size: 18px;
 }

 /* Firefox 19+ */
 :-moz-placeholder {
   color: gray;
   font-size: 18px;
 }

 /* Firefox 18- */
 :-ms-input-placeholder {
   color: gray;
   font-size: 18px;
 }
```

```html
<form novalidate>  
 <label class="required"><span class="vn invalid hide"></span>
   <input  class="name" type="name" name="name" autocomplete= none value="" placeholder="как к тебе обращаться...."  pattern="[А-Яа-яЁё]+(\s+[А-Яа-яЁё]+)?" maxlength="15" minlength="2" required><div class="iconrequired hide">ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО</div></label>


 
 <label class="required"><span  class="vn invalid hide"></span>
   <input class="name" type="name" name="name" autocomplete= none value="" placeholder="как к тебе обращаться...."  pattern="[А-Яа-яЁё]+(\s+[А-Яа-яЁё]+)?" maxlength="15" minlength="2" required><div  class="iconrequired hide">ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО</div></label>
   
</form>
```

Comment: Так в листенере у тебя же есть доступ к эвенту и его таргету. Вот и первая переменная. От нее плясать ко второй и селектить ее внутри функции. И вот валидатор стал "универсальный"

Comment: @bonusrk омг, точно event.target, но это пока не решает задачу полностью

Comment: Если совсем брутфорс, к инпуту прилепить дата-атрибут, который содержит айди целевого элемента, и опять же внутри функции за ним ходить. getElementByID стремительный как молния и ресурсов не пожрёт

Comment: @bonusrk точно, еще вариант использовать навигацию по DOM  next/previousElementSibling

Comment: Это ровно до момента, пока они соседи. Айди это надёжность, как вес.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С кэшированием ссылки на span-элемент в свойствах объекта (чтобы каждый раз не производить выборку из DOM):

```js
for (const inp of document.querySelectorAll('.mail')) 
  inp.addEventListener('input', validate);

function validate(e) {
  const target = (e instanceof Event) ? e.target : e; 
  if (!target._vn) {
    const container = target.closest('label'); 
    target._vn = container ? container.querySelector('.vn') : null; 
  }
  if (!target._vn) return;   // возможное отсутствие .vn не является настолько критичным, чтобы бросать ошибку - просто выходим 
  const isValid = target.validity.valid; 
  target._vn.classList.remove('hide'); 
  target._vn.classList.toggle('valid', isValid);    // на самом деле, два класса не нужны при таких задачах 
  target._vn.classList.toggle('invalid', !isValid); // достаточно одного (.invalid) + состояния по-умолчанию (вместо .valid)
}
```

```css
.valid { width:12px;height:12px;position:absolute;right:15px;top: 12px;background:#9dc46b;border-radius:6px;animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite  alternate inv; }
.invalid { width:12px; height:12px;position:absolute;right:15px;top: 12px;background:tomato;border-radius:6px;animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate inv; }
input:not([type="submit"]) { border-radius:100px;padding-left:15px;height:36px;border:none;background: #f3f3f3;font-size: 18px; }
input:focus { outline:none;border:2px solid #f3f3f3;box-sizing:border-box;background:white;padding-left:13px; }
.required { display:inline-flex;width:100%;flex-direction: column;margin-bottom: 15px;position:relative; }
.hide { display:none; } 

/* (стили из вопроса сжаты т.к. не менялись, и роли не играют) */
```

```html
<label class="required">
  <span class="vn invalid hide"></span>
  <input id="name" class="mail" type="name" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="имя...."  pattern="[А-Яа-яЁё]+(\s+[А-Яа-яЁё]+)?" maxlength="15" minlength="2" required>
  <div id="namereq" class="iconrequired hide">ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО</div> 
</label>

<label class="required">
  <span class="vn invalid hide"></span>
  <input id="name" class="mail" type="name" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="имя...."  pattern="[А-Яа-яЁё]+(\s+[А-Яа-яЁё]+)?" maxlength="15" minlength="2" required>
  <div id="namereq" class="iconrequired hide">ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО</div> 
</label>

<label class="required">
  <span class="vn invalid hide"></span>
  <input id="name" class="mail" type="name" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="имя...."  pattern="[А-Яа-яЁё]+(\s+[А-Яа-яЁё]+)?" maxlength="15" minlength="2" required>
  <div id="namereq" class="iconrequired hide">ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО</div> 
</label>
```

---

Но вообще для этого не нужна помощь JavaScript'a - достаточно CSS, и этот вариант оптимальнее:

```css
/* то же самое, что и в вопросе (кроме .invalid и .valid) */
input:not([type="submit"]) { border-radius:100px;padding-left:15px;height:36px;border:none;background: #f3f3f3;font-size: 18px; }
input:focus { outline:none;border:2px solid #f3f3f3;box-sizing:border-box;background:white;padding-left:13px; }
.required { display:inline-flex;width:100%;flex-direction: column;margin-bottom: 15px;position:relative; }
.hide { display:none; }

/* решение:
 * ️➕ input:placeholder-shown + .vn 
 * ➖ .valid   ➝ input:valid + .vn
 * ➖ .invalid ➝ input:invalid + .vn
 */
input:placeholder-shown + .vn { display: none; }
input:valid + .vn { width:12px;height:12px;position:absolute;right:15px;top: 12px;background:#9dc46b;border-radius:6px;animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite  alternate inv; }
input:invalid + .vn { width:12px; height:12px;position:absolute;right:15px;top: 12px;background:tomato;border-radius:6px;animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate inv; }

/* (стили из вопроса сжаты т.к. не менялись, и роли не играют) */
```

```html
<!-- span перемещен, теперь он после input, и #vn➝.vn -->
<label class="required">
  <input id="name" class="mail" type="name" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="имя...."  pattern="[А-Яа-яЁё]+(\s+[А-Яа-яЁё]+)?" maxlength="15" minlength="2" required>
  <span class="vn"></span>
  <div id="namereq" class="iconrequired hide">ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО</div> 
</label>

<label class="required">
  <input id="name" class="mail" type="name" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="имя...."  pattern="[А-Яа-яЁё]+(\s+[А-Яа-яЁё]+)?" maxlength="15" minlength="2" required>
  <span class="vn"></span>
  <div id="namereq" class="iconrequired hide">ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО</div> 
</label>

<label class="required">
  <input id="name" class="mail" type="name" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="имя...."  pattern="[А-Яа-яЁё]+(\s+[А-Яа-яЁё]+)?" maxlength="15" minlength="2" required>
  <span class="vn"></span>
  <div id="namereq" class="iconrequired hide">ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО</div> 
</label>
```

CSS-решение поддерживается современными браузерами (не поддерживается IE и Edge).

Comment: Я знаю как это можно сделать с помощью css, спасибо, вопрос про JS

Comment: Вопрос был про функцию, а не про то как это можно сделать вообще

Comment: @ПоляковРоман, Пожалуйста, не флуди в комментариях, и я добавлю в ответ еще вариант на JS.

Comment: @ПоляковРоман, JS-вариант добавлен. Есть возможность как назначения `validate` обработчиком листенера, так и прямого вызова со ссылкой на input-элемент в аргументе.